# How do you index attachment in Elasticsearch with Tire?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attachment, elasticsearch, tire

Having difficulty indexing an attachment type in **elasticsearch** via the **Tire** gem. Not able to set attachment `type` correctly.

I've taken [ActiveModel Integration example](https://github.com/karmi/tire#activemodel-integration) referenced from the Tire gem and added a field, `filename`, to reference name of PDFs on local filesystem that I want to index with the record.

```
#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  attr_accessible :title, :content, :published_on, :filename

  mapping do
    indexes :id, :type =>'integer'
    indexes :title
    indexes :content
    indexes :published_on, :type => 'date'
    indexes :attachment, :type => 'attachment' 
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json(:methods => [:attachment])
  end

  def attachment
    if filename.present?
       path_to_pdf = "/Volumes/Disk41402/test_proj/sample_pdfs/#{filename}.pdf"
       Base64.encode64(open(path_to_pdf) { |pdf| pdf.read })
    end
  end
end
```

FWIW - the PDFs appear to have been added to the index:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/articles/_all/2?pretty=true'  
{
  "_index" : "articles",
  "_type" : "article",
  "_id" : "2",
  "_version" : 1,
  "exists" : true, "_source" : {"content":"Consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. working?","created_at":"2012-06-21T17:19:03Z","filename":"sample2","id":2,"published_on":"2012-06-20","title":"Two","updated_at":"2012-06-28T00:00:59Z","attachment":"JVBERi0xLjMKJcTl8uXrp/Og0MTGCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwgL0xlbmd0aCA1IDAg\nUiAvRmlsdG...  ... ...4+CnN0YXJ0eHJlZgo4\nNTAzCiUVPRgo=\n"
}
}
```

But the attachment type is still `"type" : "string"` when it should be `"type" : "attachment"`

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/articles/_mapping?pretty=true'
{
  "articles" : {
    "article" : {
      "properties" : {
        "attachment" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "content" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "created_at" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "filename" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "published_on" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "updated_at" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried rebuilding the index `rake environment tire:import CLASS=Article FORCE=true` but type remains a string. Anyone see where I'm messing up?

**Log** (not exactly sure what 'no handler' means!?):

```
[2012-06-28 17:30:58,711][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Kofi Whitemane] [articles] deleting index
[2012-06-28 17:30:58,765][WARN ][cluster.metadata         ] [Kofi Whitemane] [articles] failed to create
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: mapping [article]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$1.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:263)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$2.run(InternalClusterService.java:211)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: No handler for type [attachment] declared on field [attachment]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:259)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(ObjectMapper.java:217)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:161)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:271)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.add(MapperService.java:174)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$1.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:260)
    ... 4 more
[2012-06-28 17:30:58,805][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Kofi Whitemane] [articles] creating index, cause [auto(bulk api)], shards [5]/[1], mappings []
[2012-06-28 17:30:58,891][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Kofi Whitemane] [articles] update_mapping [article] (dynamic)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the [mapper attachment](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments) plugin installed?

See [the tutorial at elasticsearch.org](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2011/07/18/attachment-type-in-action.html).

Comment: Yup! that was it! I had it installed but when i updated to 0.19.6 the plugin folder didn't come along for the ride. Silly me!