# fields not in mapping are included in the search results returned by ElasticSearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mapping, attachment, elasticsearch, tire

I want to index pdf attachment using Tire gem as client for ElasticSearch. In my mapping, I exclude the attachment field from _source, so that the attachment is not stored in the index and **not returned in the search results**:

```
mapping :_source => { :excludes => ['attachment_original'] } do
  indexes :id, :type => 'integer'
  indexes :folder_id, :type => 'integer'
  indexes :attachment_file_name
  indexes :attachment_updated_at, :type => 'date'
  indexes :attachment_original, :type => 'attachment'
end
```

I can still see the attachment content included in the search results when I run the following curl command:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/user_files/user_file/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "rspec"
    }
  }
}'
```

I have posted my question in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873248/how-to-prevent-attachments-from-being-stored-in-source-with-elasticsearch-and-t/11991205#comment16005481_11991205):

But I have just noticed that not only the attachment is included in the search results, but all other fields, including the ones that are not mapped, are also included as you can see here:

```
{
  "took": 20,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.025427073,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "user_files",
        "_type": "user_file",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 0.025427073,
        "_source": {
          "user_file": {
            "id": 5,
            "folder_id": 1,
            "updated_at": "2012-08-16T11:32:41Z",
            "attachment_file_size": 179895,
            "attachment_updated_at": "2012-08-16T11:32:41Z",
            "attachment_file_name": "hw4.pdf",
            "attachment_content_type": "application/pdf",
            "created_at": "2012-08-16T11:32:41Z",
            "attachment_original": "JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKNyA"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`attachment_file_size` and `attachment_content_type` are not defined in the mapping, but are returned in the search results:

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "folder_id": 1,
  "updated_at": "2012-08-16T11:32:41Z",
  "attachment_file_size": 179895, <---------------------
  "attachment_updated_at": "2012-08-16T11:32:41Z",
  "attachment_file_name": "hw4.pdf", <------------------
  "attachment_content_type": "application/pdf",
  "created_at": "2012-08-16T11:32:41Z",
  "attachment_original": "JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKNyA"
}
```

Here's my full implementation:

```
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  def self.search(folder, params)
    tire.search() do
      query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND"} if params[:query].present?
      #filter :term, folder_id: folder.id
      #highlight :attachment_original, :options => {:tag => "<em>"}
      raise to_curl
    end
  end

  mapping :_source => { :excludes => ['attachment_original'] } do
    indexes :id, :type => 'integer'
    indexes :folder_id, :type => 'integer'
    indexes :attachment_file_name
    indexes :attachment_updated_at, :type => 'date'
    indexes :attachment_original, :type => 'attachment'
  end

  def to_indexed_json
     to_json(:methods => [:attachment_original])
   end

  def attachment_original
    if attachment_file_name.present?
      path_to_original = attachment.path
      Base64.encode64(open(path_to_original) { |f| f.read })
    end    
  end
```

Could somebody help me figure out why all the fields are included in the `_source`?

**Edit:** This is the output of running `localhost:9200/user_files/_mapping`

```
{
  "user_files": {
    "user_file": {
      "_source": {
        "excludes": [
          "attachment_original"
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "attachment_content_type": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "attachment_file_name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "attachment_file_size": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "attachment_original": {
          "type": "attachment",
          "path": "full",
          "fields": {
            "attachment_original": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "author": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "title": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "date": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "dateOptionalTime"
            },
            "keywords": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "content_type": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "attachment_updated_at": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "created_at": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "folder_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "updated_at": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "dateOptionalTime"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, for some reason all the fields are included in the mapping!

Comment: In this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251851/how-do-you-index-attachment-in-elasticsearch-with-tire?rq=1 It looks like the undefined fields are also included in the mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `to_indexed_json`, you include the `attachment_original` method, so it is sent to elasticsearch. That's also the reason why all your other properties are included in the mapping and, consequently, source.

See the [ElasticSearch & Tire: Using Mapping and to_indexed_json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672072/elasticsearch-tire-using-mapping-and-to-indexed-json) question for more information on the topic.

It seems that Tire is indeed sending the proper mapping JSON to elasticsearch -- my advice is to use `Tire.configure { logger STDERR, level: "debug" }` to inspect what is happening and trz to pinpoint the problem on the raw level.

Comment: I misunderstood how to_indexed_json works. Thanks again for the link, it helps a lot.